# Table output doesn't aggregate my results by month, does each month count

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this code below that is resulting in this output,

[Output table]

[image: 1]

And i'm trying to make it aggregate in pay_countpermon like the following.  What am I doing wrong?  I feel like it's coming from my SELECT lines... thank you
[desired table aggregated in pay_countpermon]

[image: 2]

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT (first_name || ' ' || last_name) AS name, 
c.customer_id, 
p.amount, 
p.payment_date
FROM customer AS c
JOIN payment AS p
ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id),
    
t2 AS (SELECT t1.customer_id
FROM t1
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY SUM(t1.amount) DESC
LIMIT 10)
    
SELECT    
t1.name AS fullname,
t1.payment_date AS pay_mon,
COUNT (*) AS pay_countpermon,
SUM(t1.amount) AS pay_amount
FROM t1
JOIN t2
ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
WHERE t1.payment_date BETWEEN '20070101' AND '20080101'
GROUP BY pay_mon, fullname
Order by pay_countpermon DESC
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Why are you storing date values as strings?

Comment: I'm not really sure what i'm doing, so probably not intentional @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I'm using postgreSQL but right now in a test environment that acts like a SQL DBMS, i think @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Of course it "acts like a SQL DBMS" because Postgres **is** a "SQL database" - in fact **every** relational database is a "SQL database"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to `group by datepart(year,pay_mon), datepart(m,pay_mon), fullname`, which will group lines together by year and month. If you try to group by a full datetime field, it won't group them together unless the entire timestamp is identical. You need to indicate which part of the datetime you want to group on.

Here's a sample of sql I wrote recently to get a monthly count of errors from an error log by error type, which is conceptually similar to what you're trying to do I think, so will maybe help illustrate:

```
select datepart(year,ErrorTimestamp) as 'year', datepart(m,ErrorTimestamp) as 'month',  ErrorType, count(RecordId) from ErrorLog
     group by datepart(year,ErrorTimestamp), datepart(m,ErrorTimestamp), ErrorType 
     Order by datepart(year,ErrorTimestamp) desc, datepart(m,ErrorTimestamp) desc
```